# End user console.log from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a live Chrome Extension that's working fine for 15 users, but isn't functioning for a couple of them. The error that they're both encountering is below:
[image: JSON Error]

This Extension uses an API, built by our developer, that sends a JSON response to the Extension. I think if I could see the end user's JSON response, I could decipher what's going on. I'm unable to recreate the issue on my end, but I have a client who would probably be willing to help me debug.

Here's a code sample which may add clarity:

```
let requestObj2 = {
    AtsCode: result.atsmap
}
$.get('https://x.com/AtsMapping.aspx', requestObj2, (data2, status2) => {


fieldmap = JSON.parse(data2);
```

Is there a way for an end user to console.log the `data2` or `fieldmap` variables? Or somehow access them so that they can send to me?

Thanks!

Comment: [Chrome network tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/#open) might be of use, and your users could screenshot the `AtsMapping.aspx` request. I doubt there's anything directly wrong with your code; instead, whatever request response that's coming back isn't valid. **Edit:** you can go to `chrome://inspect/#extensions` to see all running extensions.

Comment: Can you just add console logging behind a "developer mode" or "debug mode" settings toggle to your source code? Or is the issue that `console.log` output from the extension doesn't appear at all.

Comment: @sheng The network tab has exactly what I need! I'm asking the client to provide me the content from hers. Hopefully we can debug from there. Thanks so much

Comment: If you perform the request in your content script it may get blocked by CORB. The preferred method is to [relay it via the background script](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches).